# Flutter Riverpod provider question - what situation would trigger a "watch" placed on a basic Provider? (code ref provided)

Tags: flutter, riverpod

With Riverpod in Flutter, what situation would actually trigger an update for a "watch" that is placed on just a basic Provider (i.e. not a StateNotifier Provider).   For example in this situation below:

```
final todosDatabaseProvider = Provider<TodosDatabase>((_) => TodosDatabaseImpl());

final todosRepositoryProvider =
    Provider<TodosRepository>((ref) => TodosRepositoryImpl(ref.watch(todosDatabaseProvider)));
```

This is from the github project here:  https://github.com/okaryo/CleanArchitectureTodoAppTrainingWithFlutter/blob/master/lib/data/data_module.dart

So what actual update from the TodosDatabaseImpl instance would trigger a "watch" type update to the todosRepositoryProvider?  And if this occured would todosRepositoryProvider be like effectively rebuilt/refreshed??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Provider` could cause its dependent to rebuild by either:

- calling `ref.refresh` on that provider:

  ```dart
  final provider = Provider((ref) => 0);
  final dependent = SomeProvider((ref) => ref.watch(provider));

  ...
  Consumer(
    builder: (context, ref, _) {
     return SomeButton(
       onPressed: () => ref.refresh(provider),
     );
    }
  )
  ```
- if that `Provider` is also using `ref.watch`, such as:

  ```dart
  final provider = Provider((ref) {
    ref.watch(anotherProvider);
    return Something();
  });
  ```

  in which case, when `anotherProvider` emits an update, `provider` will update and then things that watch `provider` will also update

Comment: thanks @Rémi - how about in the context of how this one (in my question) is used for access to a repository layer?  I mean I am wondering in this usage scenario: (a) it would be unlikely for todosDatabaseProvider & TodosDatabaseImpl to need to trigger/emit an update?  (b) what code would TodosDatabaseImpl need to carry out to trigger todosDatabaseProvider to emit an update?  (c) if I'm correct would that not mean the todosRepositoryProvider could used "read" rather than "watch"?   [so these questions are re a basic Provider...for a StateNotifierProvider this makes more sense to me ]